# Grouping of elements in XSLT except the first one

Tags: xml, xslt, grouping, sequence

(the title of this question might not be the correct one, so I will change it if someone has a better suggestion.)

I have a list of results from a sport event where I want to have the following output:

```
<p>
1) John Doe, Norway 1.23,45, 2) Dave Doe, Norway 0.15 behind, 3) Nicholas Doe, Norway Same Time, 4) Barack Doe, USA S.T, 5) Vladimir Doe, Russia 1.00,00 behind, 6) Xi Min Doe, China S.T. .... 
</p>
```

In written words:
First results has the total time. Second results uses gap and we add behind, if the third result has the same gap as the second result we give that one same time. If the fourth result has the same gap as second result, we shorten it to s.t.
If there is a new gap, we write out the gap, but all results who has the same gap as the first one in this group, shall only have s.t.

Alternative output:

```
<results>
<result>
<rank>1</rank>
<name>John</name>
<lastname>Doe</name>
<country>Norway</country>
<time>1:23:45</time>
<gap>00:00</gap>
</result>

<result>
<rank>2</rank>
<name>Dave</name>
<lastname>Doe</name>
<country>Norway</country>
<time>1:24:00</time>
<gap>00:15</gap>
</result>

<result>
<rank>3</rank>
<name>Nicholas</name>
<lastname>Doe</name>
<country>Norway</country>
<time>1:24:00</time>
<gap>same time</gap>
</result>

<result>
<rank>4</rank>
<name>Barack</name>
<lastname>Doe</name>
<country>USA</country>
<time>1:24:00</time>
<gap>s.t.</gap>
</result>

<result>
<rank>5</rank>
<name>Vladimir</name>
<lastname>Doe</name>
<country>Norway</country>
<time>1:24:45</time>
<gap>01:15</gap>
</result>

<result>
<rank>6</rank>
<name>Xi Min</name>
<lastname>Doe</name>
<country>Norway</country>
<time>1:24:45</time>
<gap>s.t.</gap>
</result>
</results>
```

the XML is quite similar to this:

```
<results>
<result>
<rank>1</rank>
<name>John</name>
<lastname>Doe</name>
<country>Norway</country>
<time>1:23:45</time>
<gap>00:00</gap>
</result>

<result>
<rank>2</rank>
<name>Dave</name>
<lastname>Doe</name>
<country>Norway</country>
<time>1:24:00</time>
<gap>00:15</gap>
</result>

<result>
<rank>3</rank>
<name>Nicholas</name>
<lastname>Doe</name>
<country>Norway</country>
<time>1:24:00</time>
<gap>00:15</gap>
</result>

<result>
<rank>4</rank>
<name>Barack</name>
<lastname>Doe</name>
<country>USA</country>
<time>1:24:00</time>
<gap>00:15</gap>
</result>

<result>
<rank>5</rank>
<name>Vladimir</name>
<lastname>Doe</name>
<country>Norway</country>
<time>1:24:45</time>
<gap>01:15</gap>
</result>

<result>
<rank>6</rank>
<name>Xi Min</name>
<lastname>Doe</name>
<country>Norway</country>
<time>1:24:45</time>
<gap>01:15</gap>
</result>
</results>
```

The output, as code:
I am using XSLT 2.0, but there might be someone out there who are using 1.0, so any suggestions supporting either (or make that all) versions of XSLT, I and many with me in the same situation would be very happy.

Comment: Please post your result **as code** and add a few words explaining what the actual problem is. -- P.S. It seems that record #4 is missing?

Comment: record #4 is missing for obvious reasons, it is similar to the rest, but I can add it.

Comment: "*record #4 is missing for obvious reasons*" I am afraid those reasons are not at all obvious to me.  I suggest you make it easy for the people who are trying to help you and not waste their time and goodwill.

Comment: I have added missing records and added a second output also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following stylesheet:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/results">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="result" group-by="gap">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="result">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="* except gap"/>
        <gap>
            <xsl:value-of select="if (position()=1) then gap else 'SAME TIME'" />
        </gap>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to your example input (after correcting the mismatching `name` and `lastname` tags!), will return:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<results>
   <result>
      <rank>1</rank>
      <name>John</name>
      <lastname>Doe</lastname>
      <country>Norway</country>
      <time>1:23:45</time>
      <gap>00:00</gap>
   </result>
   <result>
      <rank>2</rank>
      <name>Dave</name>
      <lastname>Doe</lastname>
      <country>Norway</country>
      <time>1:24:00</time>
      <gap>00:15</gap>
   </result>
   <result>
      <rank>3</rank>
      <name>Nicholas</name>
      <lastname>Doe</lastname>
      <country>Norway</country>
      <time>1:24:00</time>
      <gap>SAME TIME</gap>
   </result>
   <result>
      <rank>4</rank>
      <name>Barack</name>
      <lastname>Doe</lastname>
      <country>USA</country>
      <time>1:24:00</time>
      <gap>SAME TIME</gap>
   </result>
   <result>
      <rank>5</rank>
      <name>Vladimir</name>
      <lastname>Doe</lastname>
      <country>Norway</country>
      <time>1:24:45</time>
      <gap>01:15</gap>
   </result>
   <result>
      <rank>6</rank>
      <name>Xi Min</name>
      <lastname>Doe</lastname>
      <country>Norway</country>
      <time>1:24:45</time>
      <gap>SAME TIME</gap>
   </result>
</results>
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, that worked more or less like a charm. I did some work myself on this also and came up with a more or less similar solution. I do for-each instead of your nice solution. But that is just because I am more customed to use for-each.
After this post, I learned the following about the data: 1) If the person has the same time as the winner, gap is empty. So grouping must be done on time instead. 2) If some of the participants have accidents 3km befor the finish line, they get the same time as the winner (which I believe is an error) and gap is therefor empty. 
I'll post my version

Answer (score 0):

This was my solution to the problem. I was told after the post that only top 10 shall be rendered and so I have added a if rank <= 10 around the code.

Some part of the original data source structure here (just one to show data, names and Ids has been removed).

If you find something odd, please do not hesitate to comment or ask question.

```
<RESULT>
        <rank>42</rank>
        <bib>43</bib>
        <name>John</name>
        <surname>Doe</surname>
        <short_team>ABA</short_team>
        <long_team>ABBA</long_team>
        <time>04:42:18</time>
        <gap>13</gap>
        <code>ABA1234</code>
        <nationality>BEL</nationality>
    </RESULT>
```

The part of the XSLT to group and get the right output. Mind, this is production code, and so some text may differ from the example. I have added comments where there are differences:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="RESULT" group-by="time">
            <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                <xsl:if test="rank &lt;= 10">
                    <xsl:value-of select="rank"/>
                    <xsl:text>) </xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
                    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                    <xsl:variable name="surname">
                        <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(surname, ' ')">
                            <xsl:value-of
                                select="concat(upper-case(substring(., 1, 1)), lower-case(substring(., 2)))"/>
                            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($surname)"/>

                    <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="nationality"/>
                    <xsl:text> (</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="long_team"/>
                    <xsl:text>)</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="rank = '1'">
                            <!-- the replace is just there to get the time in the correct format -->
                            <xsl:value-of select="replace(time, ':', '.')"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="rank = '2'">
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="gap != ''">
                                    <xsl:if test="string-length(gap) = 2">
                                       <!-- this text is here because the gap might just have two characters, and we want it like this 0.12 -->
                                        <xsl:text>0.</xsl:text>
                                    </xsl:if>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="replace(gap, ':', '.')"/>
                                    <!-- This is norwegian text for minutes behind (shortened) -->
                                    <xsl:text> min. bak</xsl:text>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:otherwise>
                                    <!-- This is norwegian for same time -->
                                    <xsl:text> samme tid</xsl:text>
                                </xsl:otherwise>
                            </xsl:choose>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="position() = 1">
                                    <xsl:if test="string-length(gap) = 2">
                                        <xsl:text>0.</xsl:text>
                                    </xsl:if>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="replace(gap, ':', '.')"/>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:otherwise>
                                    <xsl:text> s.t.</xsl:text>
                                </xsl:otherwise>
                            </xsl:choose>

                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="position() != last()">
                            <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
```